# How do I resolve the below mentioned DynamoDB error?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk, boto3

**An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the PutItem operation: One or more parameter values were invalid: Type mismatch for key Xyz expected: S actual: M**

Sometimes it throws **expected: S actual: SS**

I am using boto3 for this. I am trying to put an item in DynamoDB table. Below is my python snippet:

```
from boto3.dynamodb.conditions import Key, Attr
dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb',region_name='us-west-2')
table = dynamodb.Table('Xyz-Account')
table.put_item(
    Item={
        'Xyz': {'S': xyz_num},
    })
```

*'xyz_num'* variable is string type. I cross checked that.And I have checked the table field in the dynamodb, it is a string type field and not number or any other type. Where is the mismatch occurring here ? And by the way, the function ran coolly a while ago, but then some black magic happened and this error came up. I've been trying to resolve this for 3 hours. Can anyone help ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I presume that Xyz is the hash key for your table and it's defined to be of type S. How did you check that xyz_num was of the correct type (string, not map or string set)?

Comment: I printed its type while running my code. print(type(xyz_num)) outputted string type

Comment: No issues, I found a workaround, the problem was that I was using boto3.resource instead of boto3.client. While applying the filters when using boto3.resource, the response was broken.. hence the error. There was no type mismatch actually.